# How to display images inside Mathematica with matplotlib

Tags: plotting, external-calls, python

How to display images **inside** Mathematica with matplotlib.

[image]

A new window is generated by default, but is it possible to display the picture directly in the notebook?

Like this:

[image]

related: [How to display images and plots from ExternalEvaluator?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180063/how-to-display-images-and-plots-from-externalevaluator)

Comment: What advantage would this have over generating those plots in native MMA code?

Comment: @MarcoB I assume for comparison reasons? (Also, of course some people might like ugly Python code and clunky graphics...)

Answer (score 14):

Seems to be able to embed images by converting to png.

```py
import io
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def show_plt(plot):
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plot.savefig(buf, transparent=True, format='png')
    buf.seek(0)
    im = Image.open(buf).convert("RGBA")
    buf.close()
    return im
```

[image]

In fact, matplotlib can export svg, but wolfram does not support importing svg, so there is no way to get vector graphics.

Note that this function works for all libraries that depend on matplotlib, like seaborn:

[image]

Comment: Will this work on any [raster image](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RasterImageFormats.html) format that Python can save and Wolfram Language can import? Or did you try a few raster formats and only PNG worked?